# Individual rss feed entry length for categories?

Tags: categories, rss, feed

I know how to retrieve the rss2 feed from a category in wp, namely adding `/feed` behind the category name. However when I do this, not all entries from that feed are included in the rss, this is because I set the feed restriction to be 50 at the admin backend.

I would like to know if a feed length could be set indiviually for each category/feed programatically.

I could not find any api settings for the size of the feeds ... any help is welcome here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Stephen Harris and CodeMonkey the answers both do not work for one particular category? Otherwise both answers work do work for me! Why could it be that it only does not work for one category?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *should* be able to use `pre_get_posts` and set the `posts_per_page` to 50 conditionally (on being feed for categories). Unfortunately there is this [unresolved trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17853).

The only work-around is to do hook into `post_limits` and replace the `LIMIT` part of the SQL query directly.

```
add_action('post_limits','wpse71759_category_rss_limit',10,2);
function wpse71759_category_rss_limit($limit, $query){

     if( $query->is_feed() && $query->is_category() ){
          $paged =  $query->get('paged') ? (int) $query->get('paged') : 1;
          $per_page = 50;
          $page_start = ($paged-1)*$per_page;

          return "LIMIT $page_start, $per_page";
     }
     return $limit;
}
```

Comment: Hey Stephen I will look into that, uhm actually I always want all entries from a category in a feed, and only on my blog page I want a restriction of the limit that I set in the backend, how would I do that?

Comment: In that case, `return "";` rather than `"LIMIT $page_start, $per_page"` should do it.

Comment: Hey can you explain your code a bit? I am not quite sure if that is what I want what that you are offering here.

Comment: So for category feeds you want to return *all* posts - so you don't want a `LIMIT` part to your query. The above filter, allows you to replace the `LIMIT` part with a blank string, so that the resulting sql will fetch all posts.

Comment: Can I just add that to functions.php right?

Comment: Yes, but I'd recommend making a plug-in out of it (http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-create-a-functionality-plugin/)

Comment: Stephen would posts_per_rss work with the patch offered from the trac?

Comment: I finally got it to work, also with that last category that was causing issues. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('query', 'sql_query_feed_filter');
function sql_query_feed_filter($sql){
    global $wp_query;

    if ($wp_query->is_feed == true &&  isset($wp_query->query_vars['custom_taxonomy']) &&  in_array($wp_query->query_vars['custom_taxonomy'], array('slug1','slug2')) ){
        if (strpos($sql, 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS') !== false){
            list($sql,) = explode('LIMIT', $sql);
        }
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

all you need to do is just edit this function and repalce taxonomy by your category taxonomy and edit slug to much your category...

Comment: Would you care to explain your code?

Comment: Simple SQL Query filter that trigger on feed ($wp_query->is_feed == true) if specific taxonomy found ($wp_query->query_vars['custom_taxonomy'] custom_taxonomy in example) and if it quivaluent to some slug ( $wp_query->query_vars['custom_taxonomy'] == 'slug' ). if everything of this happens and true (on a  site.com/your-custom-feed-for-category.xml ) you will get no limit results in your feed ($SQL statment divided by LIMIT value which mean it returned without last LIMIT operator... no limit. all entries per rss.)

Comment: Where would I drop that code? functions.php of my theme?

Comment: functions.php perfactly fits. but change slug and name of custom taxonomy before. and clear browser cache before testing (RSS Feeds a cached by browser).

Comment: Hey thanks for the heads up with the cache! It kind of works, but still on at least one category I will not get all posts in the feed, on others it works ...

Comment: This is what I used  `add_filter('query', 'sql_query_feed_filter');
function sql_query_feed_filter($sql){
    global $wp_query;

    if ($wp_query->is_feed == true &&  ( (isset($wp_query->query_vars['category_name']) && ($wp_query->query_vars['category_name'] == 'cat0' || $wp_query->query_vars['category_name'] == 'cat1') || $wp_query->query_vars['category_name'] == 'cat2'))) {
     //print_r($wp_query); die();
        if (strpos($sql, 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS') !== false){
            list($sql,) = explode('LIMIT', $sql);
        }
    }
    return $sql;
}`

Comment: take a look to repalced code, specialy to this part - <code>in_array($wp_query->query_vars['custom_taxonomy'], array('slug1','slug2'))</code> which just list of allowed slugs for fll list categories.