# date issue with category post retrival

Tags: posts, categories, rss, date

I am trying to retrieve all posts from an rss feed from a category, and I have working code that does this. However, on one category I will only get all posts until a certain date. Any post prior to this date will not show up. I have debugged this by posting a new article and set it as close to the last retrieved post as possible. The glitch seems to happen passing from one day into another at 00:00 (12AM). Does anyone know of such an issue.

```
add_filter('option_posts_per_rss', 'override_posts_per_rss');
function override_posts_per_rss($value){    
    if(isset($_GET['posts_per_rss']))
        return intval($_GET['posts_per_rss']);
    else
        return $value;
}
```

this is the code that I am using. It works fine for all of my other categories except for one where I hit this date barrier.

I have tried any code from this post: [Individual rss feed entry length for categories?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71759/individual-rss-feed-entry-length-for-categories) and all give the same output hitting this date barrier.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found the answer. The issue was caused by a strange enclosures from the podcasting plugin. Removed the enclosure and BAM everything is fine now!

The main think to notice: if you have such a problem, your feed is probably invalid. Validate your feed first and then see if there are any problems there!